# How to automatically execute numbers on dialpads without showing to user by clicking button

Tags: java, android

Is it possible when any users clicks on button which I created on Application, and code some numbers like *123#. When click happens then it automatically execute this without showing dialpad to User and show its responce in popup like we get.

May be it little bit confusing because I do not know how to clearly explain it. If any person know how to do that in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this a method in your button listener dialToNumberStr("0123456789")

```
public void dialToNumberStr(String numberToDial){
 //String numberToDial = "0123456789"
 Intent dialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
 dialIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:".concat(numberToDial)));
 startActivity(dialIntent); 
 }
```

your listener should be (using Lambda Expression):

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(v->{
dialToNumberStr("0123456789");
});
```

your listener should be (or the old way):

```
     myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   dialToNumberStr("0123456789");
                }
            });
```

Comment: you're welcome @MuhammadUsama, I hope it is what you're looking for, regards